# convert designer to code

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have simple code to Asp WebForms which in gridView (DevExpress) add specific data (contain 3 checkbox).

How can I write it programmatically (not in Designer)?

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid" ClientInstanceName="grid" runat="server"
             Width="100%">
<Columns>
    <dx:GridViewDataColumn Caption="YourNameHere">
        <DataItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox id="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            <asp:CheckBox id="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
            <asp:CheckBox id="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
        </DataItemTemplate>
    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
</Columns>
```

Comment: DevExpress have a support article detailing exactly how to do this: [How to create a DataItem template for a grid column at runtime](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E293)

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to implement a new class which supports the [ITemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate.aspx) interface. Use  the InstantiateIn method of this interface to create required controls which will be positioned in the template container. Then handle the page_load event and set the column's DataItemTemplate property to an instance of this class.

DevExpress published a lot of examples devoted to the runtime setup of templates:

[Examples](https://search.devexpress.com/?q=ITemplate&p=T4%7CP5%7C0&d=16)